# Any alternative for 'mailto' to submit form data from static site?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, mailto, netlify

I have created a static website.
I deployed it using netlify. But using mailto into form action is not secure on many browser.
Is there any alternative or any other method?

Comment: Netlify Forms is free to use, up to an extent. https://www.netlify.com/products/forms/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use https://www.form-data.com - a web service that provides an endpoint that you can put in your form's action, and it will handle the submission including spam filter, email notification, auto reply and integrations.
Disclosure: I'm the founder of this service

Comment: Why is the downvote? This answers the question and provides a solution for a static site with no backend.